# Time Based change of image

Tags: images, date-time

Could someone please point me in the right direction,  im currently using :

```
<?php if (get_the_time('H') >= 8 && get_the_time('H') < 20) : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/picture1.jpg" alt="randomalt2" />       
   <?php else : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/pictur2.jpg" alt="randomalt1" />    
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Which is suppose to change image at certain times of the day, currently set at 8 in the morning and 8 at night ( 20 ).

The image shows but it isnt changing, is there something ive missed ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're using the wrong function. [`get_the_time()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) doesn't actually return the current time but instead the time of when the post was published. Maybe what you're looking to use is [`date( 'H' )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 2):

The correct core function should be [`current_time()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time)

Untested, but your code ought to look something like:

```
if (current_time('H') >= 8 && current_time('H') < 20)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it returns the current time of the site/blog not the user/visitor time. But PHP after all is a server-side language..

Comment: `current_time()` returns "The local time returned is based on the timezone set on the blog's General Settings page, which is UTC by default", yes.